# Should I use a blacklist/whitelist toggle?

Tags: lists, toggle, user-preferences

I've been meaning to add a feature to my application's config files that allow you to blacklist or whitelist certain users. Which one is a better mechanic?

### Mechanic 1

#### Block certain people

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "these",
    "users",
    "are",
    "blocked"
  ],
  "whitelist": [
    "these",
    "users",
    "are",
    "always",
    "allowed"
  ]
}
```

(result: `blocked` is the only blocked user)

#### Block all except a few people

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "*"
  ],
  "whitelist": [
    "these",
    "users",
    "are",
    "allowed"
  ]
}
```

(result: `these`, `users`, `are`, `allowed` are the only allowed users)

### Mechanic 2

#### Block certain people

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "these",
    "users",
    "are",
    "blocked"
  ],
  "isWhitelist": false
}
```

(result: `these`, `users`, `are`, `blocked` are blocked)

#### Block all except a few people

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "these",
    "users",
    "are",
    "allowed"
  ],
  "isWhitelist": true
}
```

(result: `these`, `users`, `are`, `allowed` are the only allowed users)

Which one would work better and feel more intuitive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always deny all, then allow "user 1", "user 2", etc.

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "*"
  ],
  "whitelist": [
    "user 1",
    "user 2"
  ]
}
```

Keep it simple. With your other example, you have another flag "isWhitelist" to set on a block of users. It's confusing to see a property blacklist and then "isWhitelist" next to it, which specifies they're allowed. I assume they're blacklisted, because of the property's name, but then they're not because the flag "isWhitelist" allows them. It's misleading.

Look at how MS does this on IIS IP restrictions.

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"><!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
            <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
            <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" />
            <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If you want to protect a directory, you deny all, then allow certain users.It's much easier to read at a glance, and it's less confusing because it's obvious all are blacklisted except the whitelist.